# comparing the second element of tuples in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently writing a program that demonstrates the Gale-Shapley algorithm.

[Description of Gale-Shapley algorithm on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem)

I have two lists as input.

preference_boys, which is the boys' preferences on the girls and

preference_girls, which is the girls' preferences on the boys.

In the code, the first ones to choose are the boys and I have successfully managed to pair each boy

with his first choice of the girls.

```
'''
preference_boys = [[2, 0, 1, 3], [1, 2, 3, 0], [0, 3, 1, 2], [2, 3, 0, 1]]

preference_girls = [[0, 2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 2, 0], [0, 3, 1, 2]]
'''

def couple_maker(preference_boys, preference_girls):
    # stores the couples based on boys first choice of girls
    temporary_couples = []

    single_boys = []

    for boy in range(len(preference_boys)):
        single_boys.append(boy)
    # single_boys = [0, 1, 2, 3]


    while len(single_boys) > 0:
        for single_boy in single_boys:
            for girl in preference_boys[single_boy]:
                temporary_couple = (single_boy, girl)
                single_boys.remove(single_boy)
                temporary_couples.append(temporary_couple)
                break


    return temporary_couples

>>> couple_maker(preference_boys, preference_girls)
[(0, 2), (2, 0), (1, 1), (3, 2)]
```

Now, I need to make another condition to solve the case when two couples share a single girl.

From my current output of temporary_couples (0, 2) and (3, 2) couples share the same girl.

What methods can I use to compare the preferences of the overlapping girl(the second element

of the tuple in the list) and remove the couple that has the boy with a lower priority to the girl?

Comment: @Ayxan for list preference_boys, the elements in the nested lists are each boy's preference of the girls from highest to lowest. for list preference_girls, the nested lists are each girl's preference of the boys. Since boys are first ones to choose and assuming that they all grab the girl of their first choice, from preference boys I can have [(0,2), (1,1), (2,0), (3,2)]. My problem is dealing with the shared girl which is physically impossible to happen for the girl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, would be to group the `temporary_couples` "by girl" (the 1th index), using something like a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

temp_couples = [(0, 2), (2, 0), (1, 1), (3, 2)]

by_girl = defaultdict(list)

for (b,g) in temp_couples:
    by_girl[g].append((b,g))

for (g,her_temp_couples) in by_girl.items():
    if len(her_temp_couples) > 1:
        print("Girl", g, "has conflicts:", her_temp_couples)
```

Output:

```
Girl 2 has conflicts: [(0, 2), (3, 2)]
```

Then you could go on to resolve the same way the algorithm you cited does.

For clarity, after it's populated in the first loop, `by_girl` looks like:

```
{
  0: [(2, 0)], 
  1: [(1, 1)]
  2: [(0, 2), (3, 2)],
  3: []                # Implicitly      
}
```